# Proving two identities (trace and determinant)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am given that,

$$\mathbf{B_{k+1}=B_k-\frac{B_ks_ks_k^TB_k}{s_k^TB_ks_k}+\frac{y_ky_k^T}{y_k^Ts_k}}$$

where $\mathbf{B_k}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $\mathbf{s,y}$ are $n$ vectors. I need to show that

\begin{equation}
\det(\mathbf{B_{k+1}})=\det(\mathbf{B_k})\mathbf{\frac{y_k^Ts_k}{s_k^TB_ks_k}} \\
\text{tr}(\mathbf{B_{k+1}})=\text{tr}(\mathbf{B_k})-\mathbf{\frac{||B_ks_k||^2}{s_k^TB_ks_k}+\frac{||y||^2}{y_k^Ts_k}}
\end{equation}

---

1. For the first identity, I know that
   $$\mathbf{\det(I+xy^T+uv^T)} =\mathbf{\det(I+y^Tx+v^Tu)}=(1+\mathbf{y^Tx})(1+\mathbf{v^Tu)-(x^Tv)(y^Tu)},$$ but for the term, $\mathbf{\frac{B_ks_ks_k^TB_k}{s_k^TB_ks_k}}$, what would considered $\mathbf{x}\ \text{and} \ \mathbf{y^T}$?
2. I know that 
   \begin{align*}
   \text{tr}(\mathbf{B_{k+1}}) = \text{tr}\left(\mathbf{B_k}-\frac{\mathbf{B_ks_ks_k^TB_k}}{\mathbf{s_k^TB_ks_k}}+\frac{\mathbf{y_ky_k^T}}{\mathbf{y_k^Ts_k}}\right) \\
   =\text{tr}(\mathbf{B_k})-\text{tr}\left(\mathbf{\frac{B_ks_ks_k^TB_k}{s_k^TB_ks_k}}\right)+\text{tr}\left(\mathbf{\frac{y_ky_k^T}{y_k^Ts_k}}\right)
   \end{align*}

But I don't know how the numerators of the second and third terms are becoming squared norms.

Comment: Why are you tagging these questions with 'optimization'?

Comment: @StubbornAtom because it is quasi-Newton methods (BFGS) see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method).

Comment: @StubbornAtom it improves the likelihood of getting an answer as this identity comes from optimization. It's the BFGS method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, let's drop the subscript $k$. We know that
\begin{align*}
  & \det\left(B-\frac{Bss'B}{s'Bs} + \frac{yy'}{y's}\right) \\
= & \det\left(B\left(I-\frac{ss'B}{s'Bs} + \frac{B^{-1}yy'}{y's}\right)\right) \\
= & \det(B)\det\left(I-\frac{ss'B}{s'Bs} + \frac{B^{-1}yy'}{y's}\right).
\end{align*}
Use your first identity, make $-\frac{s}{s'Bs}$ as $\mathbf{x}$, $Bs$ as $\mathbf{y}$, $B^{-1}y$ as $\mathbf{u}$, and $\frac{y}{y's}$ as $\mathbf{v}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
& \det\left(I-\frac{ss'B}{s'Bs} + \frac{B^{-1}yy'}{y's}\right) \\
= & \left(1-\frac{s'Bs}{s'Bs}\right)\left(1+\frac{y'B^{-1}y}{y's}\right)
  + \frac{s'y}{s'Bsy's}\times s'BB^{-1}y \\
= & \frac{s'y}{s'Bs} = \frac{y's}{s'Bs}.
\end{align*}

For the trace part,  note that $\text{tr}\,Bss'B = \text{tr}\,s'BBs = ||Bs||$, and $\text{tr}\,yy' = \text{tr}\,y'y = ||y||$.

Comment: @Guangling, thank you for your insight! For the trace part, should it be $\text{tr}(s'BBs)=||Bs||\mathbf{^2}$ not $||Bs||$?

Comment: Yes, you're right, should be squared, same for $||y||^2$. Sorry for the sloppiness.